# how to generate students mark ledger from 3 tables- Student,Mark,Subject

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, report

I have four tables  
1.student-it contains id name etc 
2.marks - it contains markid,student_id,batch,class,section,subject_id,exam_id,obt_mark 
3.subject table - it contains sub_id,sub_name
4. exam_type- examtype_id, exam_name 

i need mark ledger for batch-2014,class=5,section=1,exam_id=3 as shown below-

```
    NAME   ROLL NO   SUB1   SUB2    SUB3  TOTAL  RESULT  POSITION RANK
    RAM     0054     65     54      64     183     PASS    FIRST    2
    HAri    0054     65     54      65     184     PASS    FIRST    1
    gopal   0054     65     50      65     180     PASS    FIRST    3
    saroj   0054     65     44      65     174     PASS    FIRST    4
```

Thanks in advance .

Here i have sql query

```
                                  
SELECT `marklists`.`mrk_sub_id1`, `marklists`.`mrk_marks`, `marklists`.`mrk_practical`,
`marklists`.`mrk_exam_type`, `students`.`id` as st_id, `students`.`st_roll`, 
`students`.`st_name`, `students`.`batch`, `students`.`st_class`, 
`students`.`st_section`,   `courses`.`id`, `classes`.`class_name` as class_name,    
`courses`.`sb_name` as subject_name, `courses`.`sb_fullmark` as full_marks,     
`courses`.`sb_passmark` as pass_marks FROM (`marklists`)
 LEFT JOIN `classes` ON   `marklists`.`mrk_class` = `classes`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `students`  ON   `marklists`.`mrk_student_id`=`students`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `courses` ON   `marklists`.`mrk_sub_id`=`courses`.`id` 
WHERE `marklists`.`mrk_exam_type` = '3' AND   `marklists`.`mrk_batch` = '3' 
AND `marklists`.`mrk_class` = '1' AND   `marklists`.`mrk_section` = '1'
```

and I need ledger like above any help??

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables based on common key and for the titles which you need as subject you can use pivot operator to convert rows to column and use where clause for rest of the conditions
   hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks  here i have sql result array

Comment: Thank you for your response in my  problem , i'm not sure how to pivot the result array so i had add my sql in my question.